(Solved) The route is wrongly configured using JWTRefreshTokenBundle on Symfony 7.0.7
I am encountering an error when testing my /api/token/refresh endpoint with the JWTRefreshTokenBundle library. The following error appears:
Unable to find the controller for path "/api/token/refresh". The route is wrongly configured.
I am using Symfony 7.0.7 and have followed the steps in the official documentation of JWTRefreshTokenBundle. My endpoint 'api/login_check' correctly returns the token and refresh_token, but when I call the URL /api/token/refresh, I get the error.
Here are my configurations for the JWT bundle:
"gesdinet/jwt-refresh-token-bundle": "1.3.0"
"lexik/jwt-authentication-bundle": "3.0.0"
I tried the solutions proposed on the JWTRefreshTokenBundle repo
security.yaml:
security:
    password_hashers:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface: 'auto'
    providers:
        app_user_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\User
                property: email
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        login:
            pattern: ^/api/login
            stateless: true
            json_login:
                check_path: /api/login_check
                username_path: email
                password_path: password
                success_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
                failure_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure
            refresh_jwt:
                check_path: /api/token/refresh
        api:
            pattern: ^/api
            stateless: true
            jwt: ~
        main:
            lazy: true
            provider: app_user_provider

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/api/(login|token/refresh), roles: PUBLIC_ACCESS }
        - { path: ^/api/users/register, roles: PUBLIC_ACCESS }
        - { path: ^/api/doc, roles: PUBLIC_ACCESS }
        - { path: ^/api, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }

config/routes.yaml:
controllers:
    resource:
        path: ../src/Controller/
        namespace: App\Controller
    type: attribute

api_login_check:
    path: /api/login_check

api_refresh_token:
    path: /api/token/refresh

config/routes.yaml:
controllers:
    resource:
        path: ../src/Controller/
        namespace: App\Controller
    type: attribute

api_login_check:
    path: /api/login_check

api_refresh_token:
    path: /api/token/refresh

config/routes/gesdinet_jwt_refresh_token.yaml:
gesdinet_jwt_refresh_token:
    path: /api/token/refresh

config/packages/gesdinet_jwt_refresh_token.yaml:
gesdinet_jwt_refresh_token:
    refresh_token_class: App\Entity\RefreshToken

||-----||
I found the solution; it was an error in the security.yaml configuration.
Here is the working version:
security:
    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#registering-the-user-hashing-passwords
    password_hashers:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface: 'auto'
    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#loading-the-user-the-user-provider
    providers:
        app_user_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\User
                property: email
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        api:
            pattern: ^/api
            stateless: true
            entry_point: jwt
            json_login:
                check_path: /api/login_check 
                username_path: email
                password_path: password
                success_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
                failure_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure
            jwt: ~
            refresh_jwt:
                check_path: /api/token/refresh 
        main:
            lazy: true
            provider: app_user_provider

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/api/(login|token/refresh), roles: PUBLIC_ACCESS }
        - { path: ^/api/users/register, roles: PUBLIC_ACCESS }
        - { path: ^/api/doc, roles: PUBLIC_ACCESS }
        - { path: ^/api, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }

